# How do I fix this form with a script running?

Tags: javascript, search, slideshow

I'm building a photo archive website for a photographer and on top of each page there is a search bar. It's pretty useful, since you only have to click on the text inside (which says: "Search the archive...") so you can enter your search phrases.

Website: bit.ly/1RB1VCv (direct link to the - now - hidden page)

Since I added a slider to the home page (javascript), the search bar seem to be partially messed up (I now have to delete the text instead of just clicking on it).

I tried to determine which part was causing trouble by deleting certain parts of the slider code I put between the body-tags in the index file:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          $('#slides').slidesjs({
            width: 1000,
            height: 300,
            play: {
              active: true,
              auto: true,
              interval: 4000,
              swap: true
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
```

Not sure if it is any helpful, but this would be the part from the header file in regards to the search bar:

```
<div id="searchBar">
{* Header Search Box Area *}
{if $config.settings.search}
    <form action="{linkto page="search.php"}" method="get" id="searchFormTest">
    <input type="hidden" name="clearSearch" value="true">
    <div class="headerSearchBox"><input type="text" id="searchPhrase" name="searchPhrase" class="searchInputBox" value="{$lang.enterKeywords}"></div>
    {if $currentGallery.gallery_id}<div class="headerSearchBox headerSearchBoxCG"><input type="checkbox" name="galleries" id="searchCurrentGallery" value="{$currentGallery.gallery_id}" checked="checked"> <label for="searchCurrentGallery">{$lang.curGalleryOnly}</label></p></div>{/if}
    <div class="eyeGlass"></div>
    <div class="headerSearchBox headerSearchBoxOption"><a href="{linkto page='search.php'}">{$lang.advancedSearch}</a></div>
    </form>
{/if}
```

Is this an obvious mistake I'm making? Is it something that can be resolved real simple? I tried to look on both Stackoverflow and Google if I could find similar problems, but that didn't help me much.

I like to hear your thoughts and if you need any other code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit of mess but I think the problem is you're putting a JQuery down in the middle and it's ruining your public.min.js, cause it tries to add a function to JQuery (the clicktoggle). So this listener is not being called:

`$('.searchInputBox').click(function(){ $(this).val(''); } );`

Basically, try to put this jquery tag BEFORE the script tag that calls your public.min.js

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

If this doesn't work, there's another problem somewhere, but as a workaround could just put the listener after all the code (create a script tag in the end of your file, it's going to work)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to use the listener to make it work. Adding the jquery tag didn't make any difference.

Comment: It wasn't just to add the jquery tag, but to remove it from where it was before (you had a jquery down in the middle of the index page, you should remove it and put if before the public.min.js tag). But if you did it and didn't work, so there's something elsewhere. Anyway, I'm glad I could help